# Development - Custom Payment Gateway

Tags: wordpress, civicrm.settings.php

Wordpress with CiviCRM 5.3.2

Good Day!

we are developing custom payment gateway for civicrm.
  in Payment Processor Settings  we need to create a login screen to get our 
  gateway account details instead of "Processor Details for Live Payments" settings using different form elements is there anyway to develop .

[image]

Thanks a lot for any suggestion or help .

Comment: Hi @Lakshmi what payment processor are you trying to create ?

Comment: For our Organisation we are creating by following this link
https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/extensions/payment-processors/create/

Comment: https://civicrm.org/blog/guest/new-extension-civicrm-online-worldpay-payment-processor

Comment: have a look at the above link also their are many custom payment processor written already - I did ask you the name of the payment processor - is it Worldpay or Sagepay etc just to make sure you are not repeating

Comment: before doing anything in civiCRM better read the Payment processor first and understand how it works and then try to find the correct way in CiviCRM - Need help Ping me - thanks

Comment: Hi Lakshmi - this is confusing to me - i understand english may not be your first language. Your question says "we are developing custom payment gateway for civicrm"  - which makes it sounds like you are developing a new solution, then you say that you are using this extension https://civicrm.org/extensions/click-pledge-payment-gateway

Answer (score 1):

Which payment gateway are you wanting to develop?  If it is one supported by [Omnipay](https://github.com/thephpleague/omnipay) then take a look at the [Omnipay Multiprocessor Extension](https://civicrm.org/extensions/omnipay-multiprocessor-extension)

If you are considering any work in this area I'd strongly encourage you to discuss this in the ~dev-financial channel on [CiviChat](https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm)

As regards Settings - there are significant changes coming up in 5.8 [as described by Eileen here](https://lists.civicrm.org/lists/arc/civicrm-dev/2018-11/msg00001.html)

Comment: Our gateway link https://civicrm.org/extensions/click-pledge-payment-gateway and its not supported by Omnipay.